# Gota sum values in a dataframe

Tags: go, gota

I'm looking to get a column sum for a dataframe using [Gota's cool dataframe in go](https://godoc.org/github.com/kniren/gota).

I see from [here](https://github.com/kniren/gota#function-application) that there's a way to apply functions to series which seems fine, that is doing:

```
mean := func(s series.Series) series.Series {
    floats := s.Float()
    sum := 0.0
    for _, f := range floats {
        sum += f
    }
    return series.Floats(sum / float64(len(floats)))
}
df.Cbind(mean)
df.Rbind(mean)
```

eg, just remove the division to get the sum function rather than the mean.  That said, if I'm only looking to sum 1 column, am I stuck writing my own easy sum function, or is there something more idiomatic and built-in like R's

```
sum(df[,c("mycol")])
```

?

I'm currently working with:

```
    sum := func(s series.Series) series.Series {
    floats := s.Float()
    sum := 0.0
    for _, f := range floats {
        sum += f
    }
    return series.Floats(sum)
    }

df.Select([]string{"mycol"})).CBind(sum)
```

where df after I subset to only the column of interest becomes:

```
[31x1] DataFrame

    mycol
 0: 8.300000            
 1: 8.300000            
 2: 16.750000           
 3: 9.030000            
    ...                 
    <float>
```

And I get something like:

```
cannot use sum (type func(series.Series) series.Series) as type dataframe.DataFrame in argument to df.Select([]string literal).CBind
```

## UPDATE

Ah, partial solution in that the documentation uses Cbind/Rbind where I think Capply/Rapply was meant, as these are documented [here](https://godoc.org/github.com/kniren/gota/dataframe#DataFrame.Rapply).  That said, the idiom question stands in that it would be great if there are built-ins I'm missing.

Comment: I think you meant to add `Capply` instsead of  `CBind`.